# Including (not excluding) groups in TestNG and Gradle

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, testng

I'm running on to issues when trying to include tests to run with TestNG using Gradle and Java. Excluding test groups works without any problem, but if I do not specify an exclude group and try to use just an include include statement, other tests get run as well.

My Gradle code is like the following:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    maxParallelForks = 1
    forkEvery = 1000
    ignoreFailures = false

    systemProperties = System.getProperties()

    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true

    exclude '**/tasks/'

    classpath += configurations.testCompile
}
```

Include example:

Exclude example; works perfectly:

```
task firefox(type: Test) {
    maxParallelForks = Integer.valueOf(threadCount) //default is 1 if not specified
    testLogging.events "started"
    testLogging {
        events "started", "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
        exceptionFormat "full" // default is "short"
    }
    useTestNG() {
        excludeGroups 'chrome', 'broken'
        useDefaultListeners = false
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
        listeners << 'com.xmatters.testng.Listener'
    }

    reports.junitXml.destination = file("${buildDir}/test-results/firefox")
    reports.html.destination = file("${reporting.baseDir}/firefox")

    systemProperties.BROWSER = System.getProperty('BROWSER', 'firefox')
    exclude '**/selenium/'
    exclude '**/setupscripts/'
}
```

This is the one giving me trouble. It including ungrouped tests in additition to those that are in the `msie` group.

```
task internetExplorer(type: Test) {
    testLogging {
        events "started", "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
        exceptionFormat "full"
    }
    useTestNG() {
        includeGroups 'msie'
        useDefaultListeners = false
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
        listeners << 'com.xmatters.testng.Listener'
    }
    reports.junitXml.destination = file("${reporting.baseDir}/internetExplorer")
    reports.html.destination = file("${buildDir}/test-results/internetExplorer")

    systemProperties.BROWSER = System.getProperty('BROWSER', 'internetExplorer')

    exclude '**/selenium/'
    exclude '**/setupscripts/
```

Any help or ideas would be great.

Comment: Could be a bug. Have you searched http://issues.gradle.org?

Comment: Only briefly, I'll give it a more thorough look and see if I can find anything that's related.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are not using the "parallel" and "threadcount" options for the Gradle TestNG plugin. Instead you are forking from Gradle core.   Take another look at this:  http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/groovydoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/testng/TestNGOptions.html

Comment: I was under the impression that using the `parallel` feature is on the project level where `maxParallelForks` runs on the task level. I only ever run one task (with multiple tests) at a time.

Comment: `useTestNG { parallel = ...; threadCount = ...; }` is the TestNG feature to execute tests in multiple threads (one JVM). `test.maxParallelForks` is the generic Gradle feature to execute (JUnit or TestNG) tests in multiple JVMs (one thread per JVM). `--parallel` is the generic Gradle feature to run tasks in parallel. (Currently, only tasks from different projects will run in parallel.)

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Interesting, this may solve a custom listener issue I've been experiencing if the tests do get run in one JVM. I took this project on when `maxParallelForks` was already in-place so I assumed there was a reason it was being done this way; perhaps not. I'll give it a go. Thanks for the tip! Still no love with the includeGroups unfortunately; it seems there have been some defect reports filed about this issue but nothing really conclusive as to whether they're verified bugs or just config issues.

Comment: It's entirely conceivable that one might run into some bad interaction between TestNG features and Gradle test parallelization, or TestNG parallelization and Gradle test features. It might not be possible to make every combination work. If you can post a self-contained minimal example that demonstrates your problem over at http://forums.gradle.org, we'll have another look.

Answer (score 0):

I use the testNG() section to set the includes and excludes

```
   useTestNG() {
        //run classes in parallel, thread count limited by processor.
        options {
            parallel = 'classes'
            threadCount = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
        }
        listeners << 'com.automation.listeners.TestNgListener'
        //sets the default group to run as smoke.*, .* is wildcard.
        includeGroups System.getProperty('groups', 'smoke.*')
        excludeGroups System.getProperty('excludeGroups', 'exclude')
    }
```

When using the above structure all ungrouped test are not ran, but I make an effort to not have any tests without groups.